# Replaced div is not working Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Basically I replaced the div in the content as soon as I click "Delete" on the Setting menu above. Well it does changes from collapsible set into checkbox with footer below containing two buttons. The buttons are delete and cancel but I can't perform anything with those buttons. For example, If Cancel clicked it should pop the alert popup (For the sake of testing). Please help..

```
<div data-role="content">
<a href="#popupKatagoriPengeluaran" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Tambah Katagori</a>

<div id="Outcome" data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"></div>
        </div>





     $("#Delete").click(function(){


    $("#Outcome").replaceWith('<form><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="OutcometoDelete">');

    db.transaction (function (transaction) 
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM KatagoriPengeluaran";
        transaction.executeSql (sql,[],
        function (transaction, result)
        {

            if (result.rows.length)
            {   



                for(var i = 0; i< result.rows.length; i++ ) {
                All2 =result.rows.item(i);
                element = $(' <input type="checkbox" name="'+All2.Katagori+'" id="'+All2.Katagori+'"><label for="'+All2.Katagori+'">'+All2.Katagori+'</label>').appendTo($('#OutcometoDelete'));

                }
                All2 =result.rows.item((result.rows.length-1));
                $('#'+All2.Katagori).append('</form></fieldset>');
                $("#OutcometoDelete").append('<div id="someFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><div id ="navbarFooter" data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a data-role="button" href="#popUpDelete">Delete</a></li><li><a  data-role="button" href="index.html#Pengeluaran" data-ajax="false" id="cancelDelete" >Cancel</a></li></ul></div></div>');
                $("#OutcometoDelete").trigger('create');
                $("#someFooter").trigger('pagecreate');
                $('#navbarFooter').trigger('pagecreate');
            }
            else
            {
                alert ("Retrieval Error");
            }




            }, error);
    });




    });

    $("#cancelDelete").click(function(){
    alert("oi");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your way of event binding will not work for future elements. You can't just bind click event and expect it will work in the future, event(s) must be bind to something inside the DOM.

So this code will not work:

```
$("#cancelDelete").click(function(){
    alert("oi");
});
```

On the other hand this code will work:

```
$(document).on('click',"#cancelDelete",function(){
    alert("oi");
});
```

Second code will work because event is bind to document and it will propagate as soon as needed element is part of the DOM and appropriate event is trigger on it. This is also called delegated event binding.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Thanks,it works! However, as you can see I develop it for jquery mobile, so does that also work for the mobile end? I thought the part  `$("#OutcometoDelete").trigger('create');`
 `$("#someFooter").trigger('pagecreate');`
already solve the problem. Or any other idea to make it really ready loaded for jquery mobile?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you use this code, as long it uses jQuery. Solution I show you is how you should bound events with jQuery now. .trigger('create') and .trigger('pagecreate') create don't have nothing to do with this. They will only enhance UI markup, they will not move events from one element to another. Plus those two functions are deprecated, you should use .enhanceWithin() instead (as of jQuery Mobile 1.4).